# macOS Monterey: System Data taking up half of the ssd ( 256gb m1 MacBook Air)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

System data is taking up half of my drive. How can I solve this problem?[image]

Comment: How do you know this? Show us the reports. It takes much less on my mini

Comment: @mmmmmm I've added the reports

Comment: Most of those are not System - e.g. Documents are all yours and Applications much of that is not Apple supplied

Comment: @mmmmmm yes, but system data is 112,36 GB, Documents is only 19,11 GB

Comment: That 112.36 is not real Systems data ie Apple supplied as macOD - look at the other question and get a better report

Comment: Apple's categories should not be trusted too highly. "System Data" includes stuff in /Library and ~/Library. Ideally, I would recommend using an app like OmniDiskSweeper to sort your disk by size, and thereby show you what's taking up the space.